# TFS 2012 Express does not seem to work out of the box if I install VS2010?

Tags: tfs, permissions

I get this error when I attempt to add a new project to Source control after a fresh installation... It seems when I am not installing VS2010 I do not get this..

Can anyone help  ?  I suppose I need permissions.. but WHO needs permission to what exactly ?

TF206018: The items could not be added to source control because either no team projects have been set up, or because you do not have permission to access any of the team projects in the current collection.

Comment: Even though this was closed it helped me! I made the same mistake!

Answer (score 9):

Sorry.. I am a dummy.. A COLLLECTION.. needs a TEAM PROJECT and THEN you add the project to source control.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped me. I am dummy too. Can you suggest any good resource to learn about TFS?